# is event.target deprecated?

Tags: javascript, html

[MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target#Specifications) specifications table for `event.target` indicates that it's status is obsolete in DOM level 2 and DOM4. does it mean it's deprecated and I no longer should use it?
If so what should I use instead?
I know my question is somehow ridiculous, cause event.target is so important and we use it everywhere, but I couldn't find something useful on the net, specially W3.org, and I'm still obsessed with the word `Obsolete` :), so I preferred to ask here. thanks

Comment: The DOM Living Standard supersedes the other standards. So the older ones are obsolete. It's not going anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're misinterpreting MDN.

It says that the DOM4 and Document Object Model (DOM) Level 2 Events Specification's **definitions** of `Event.target` are obsolete, not that `Event.target` itself is obsolete.

The DOM (Living Standard) specification is *not* marked as obsolete and you should use that definition.

Answer (score 1):

MDN documentation is prepared like so that you should not see the specification level that are obsolete. What you need to look at is to check out the current living standard. The status denoted by `obsolete` is just that specification not the method or property itself.

When any method or property is marked as obsolete, you'll see them in top like below. For eg. check [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/eval):

> Obsolete
>   This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.